# Symfony , devolver un Json con todos los campos

Tags: php, symfony2, symfony3, symfony

tengo una entidad de nombre "Cursos" que tiene una serie de atributos y uno de ellos es "shop" que es una relación onetomany con una
entidad "Shop"

En el controlador tengo hecha una acción que lo que hace es devolver un JSON aplicando una serie de filtros de búsqueda , esto lo uso luego con  bootstrap-table para presentarlo visualmente

En el controlador tengo este código

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @Route("/find/", name="admin_curso_find")
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function findAcademicProgram(Request $request)
{
    $search=$request->query->get('search');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT a FROM AppBundle:AcademicAgreement a 
             where a.code LIKE :search ')
        ->setParameter('search', '%' . $search . '%');

    $ap = $query->getArrayResult();

    return new JsonResponse($ap);
}
```

Y esto me devuelve un JSON de este estilo

> [{"id":1,"code":"12213","enabled":false,"createdAt":null,"updatedAt":null,"disabledAt":{"date":"2018-01-18
>   09:36:49.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe/Berlin"}}

Pero en la entidad tengo otro campo como el "shop" que es la relación que menciono anteriormente y este campo
no me lo devuelve el código anterior.

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que debes realizar, ya que estás creando una query usando `$em->createQuery()` es establecer la relación directamente usando un Join, ya que no estás usando los mapeadores de doctrine, sino creando una query 'manual'

debería quedar algo parecido a lo siguiente

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT c, s FROM bundle::curso c 
         join bundle:shop as s where c.id = s.curso_id 
             where c.code LIKE :search ')
        ->setParameter('search', '%' . $search . '%');
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo general, Doctrine tiene seteado como default el patron "Lazy Loading" para las relaciones entre entidades. Es por eso que, al traerte tus datos, convertirlos a array y luego convertirlos como json no ves la entidad relacionada.

La forma correcta de devolver entidades en formato JSON o Array es usar un **serializer**. Esto te permite tener el control exacto sobre como vas a mostrar o exponer las propiedades de tu entidad.

Te recomiendo [JMS Serializer](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer) o directamente el [Componente de Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html)

Ambos son bastante faciles e intuitivos de utilizar.

Espero haberte ayudado!

Comment: Revisar [answer].

Comment: @Jorgesys muchas gracias por tu ayuda